# Python File Functions

Tags: python, function

I am working on a pointless guessing game for skill development. I decided to write code to read users and their scores from a file, then write a function to check whether there username is currently in the file already:

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()

def userExists(username): 
    f = open('score.txt', 'rU')
    for line in f:
         row = line.split('\r\n')
         info = row[0].strip('\r\n').split(':')
         username = info[0]
         if user==username: 
             uExists = True
             break
         else:
             uExists = False
     return usExists
     f.close()
```

At first I had the return values, `True` and `False` inside the loop which caused problems, so I set a variable to the value and `return` that instead.

The `score.txt` looks like and uses the format of:

```
user:10:50
userB:5:10
```

But whenever I use this function `userExists('nonExistingUser')` it always returns `True` regardless if the user exists or not, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are overwriting the 'username' variable. Should do user = info[0] instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a little cluttered, so first I present a slightly cleaned-up version whose operation should (if I am correct) be pretty much the same.

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()

def userExists(username): 
    f = open('score.txt', 'rU')
    for line in f:
        username = line.rstrip().split(':')[0]
        if user==username: 
            return True
    return False
    f.close()
```

The `rstrip()` method call returns the same string without any trailing whitespace; the `split()` call returns a list of the three strings separated by colons, and you already know what the `[0]` does.The `uexists` flag turns out to be unnecessary. I presumed you wanted to remove all white space from the end of the line?

This does have the unfortunate problem that the file never gets closed (as does your suggested code). A relatively easy (but rather advanced) fix is to use the file as a context manager.

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()

def userExists(username): 
    with open('score.txt', 'rU') as f:
        for line in f:
            username = line.rstrip().split(':')[0]
            if user==username: 
                return True
        return False
```

This ensures that no matter how the function returns the file will be properly closed without needing to explicitly call its `close()` method.

Comment: works perfect now thanks, although think you made a typo, you put rline in the loop instead of line?

Comment: Good eye! Thanks, you will see I have made that correction.

Comment: there was 2 lines which contained rline in both blocks, you only changed one lol

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what JAvier pointed out, you're also setting `uExists` but returning `usExists` it should be along these lines:

```
def userExists(username):
    f = open('score.txt', 'rU')
    uExists = False
    for line in f:
         row = line.split('\r\n')
         info = row[0].strip('\r\n').split(':')
         if user==info[0]: 
             uExists = True
             break
         else:
             uExists = False
     f.close()
     return uExists
```

Depending upon your version of python, I'd also look into the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to clean up that `f.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify userExists like so:

```
def userExists(username):
    with open('score.txt','rU') as score:
        return username+':' in score.read()
```

You may wish to use a regular expression instead of username+':'

Answer (score 0):

Use files with the  `with` statement, that way the file is automatically closed when you exit the `with` block even if you leave it with an exception or a `return` statement.

```
def userExists(username):
    with open('score.txt', 'rU') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line[:line.find(':')] == username:
                return True
    return False
```